# StreamConsumedError() exception raised by "for chunk in response.iter_content(1024)"

Tags: python, python-2.7, exception, python-requests

I'm not fully sure what's the best way to ask this question,

but i'm writing a script to download some content from the internet using request.get(), everything working fine, but for some reason now getting a StreamConsumedError() being raised, and i'm not sure why.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./pythonDL-ver_0.0.4.py", line 90, in <module>
for chunk in response.iter_content(1024):
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 766, in iter_content
raise StreamConsumedError()
requests.exceptions.StreamConsumedError
```

If you need anymore information I can add it in. Thanks.

```
while True:
    count = count + 1
    print 'testing ' + str(count) + '\n'
    print url
    url_2 = url.format(count = count)
    print '////' + str(url_2) + ' for loop ' + str(count) + "////\n"


    print str(url_2) + ' testing url \n'

    filename = posixpath.basename(url_2)
    print str(filename) + ' testing filename \n'
    response = requests.get(url_2, stream = True)
    responseString = str(response)

    print str(responseString) + 'testing res2 \n'

    if responseString == '<Response [404]>':
        print '......No more Requests......\n'
        break
    elif responseString == '<Response [200]>':
        print '......Successful Request....\n'
    else:
        break

    print responseString

    while responseString == '<Response [200]>':
        print 'testing while loop: ' + str(responseString)
        with open(filename, 'wb') as fp:
            for chunk in response.iter_content(1024):
                fp.write(chunk)

    count += 1
    print str(count) + ' = counting value'
```

Here's the loop where things stopped working.

Comment: Example code will definitely help

Comment: I've added the loop where things started to go wrong, hope it makes sense.

Comment: You're trying to loop over the same response's `iter_content` repeatedly.

Comment: Ohh.. silly me, I didn't notice that, it works now, thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
    while responseString == '<Response [200]>':
        print 'testing while loop: ' + str(responseString)
        with open(filename, 'wb') as fp:
            for chunk in response.iter_content(1024):
                fp.write(chunk)
```

This loop never terminates, once `responseString` is `<Response [200]>` it stays so forever, because nothing changes that.

The only thing that prevents the loop to go forever is that you can read from streaming response several times. So when loop tries again response throws an error.

the simplest fix would be to replace `while` with `if`

```
    if responseString == '<Response [200]>':
        with open(filename, 'wb') as fp:
            for chunk in response.iter_content(1024):
                fp.write(chunk)
```

Comment: Ahh, great stuff, thanks Nazarii. Also thank you for the explanation.